# Identifier declared as unused in obj c, even though it is declared

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, nsdictionary, undeclared-identifier

I'm having issues with an NSDictionary for loop. The dictionary is called 'beach' but within the loop beach is undeclared. Here's the code

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSArray *results = [jsonString JSONValue];


for (NSDictionary *beach in results);             //beach is flagged as unused
{
  NSString *Name = [beach objectForKey:@"Name"];  //beach is flagged as undeclared
  NSLog(Name);
}

}
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spurious semi-colon in your `for` statement:

```
for (NSDictionary *beach in results); 
//                                  ^
```

Which makes your code equivalent to:

```
for (NSDictionary *beach in results)
    ;

{
    NSString *Name = [beach objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(Name);
}
```

Comment: Nice one, can't believe I missed that!